# Symfony2 FOSUserBundle relates to another Entity automatically

Tags: symfony, orm, doctrine, entity, fosuserbundle

I recently implemented the FOSUserBundle in my website as the login procedure. I want it to expand the Author class. So whenever a new user is registered via the FOSUSerBundle a new entry is created in the Author class. Inside the Author class I set slug, createdAt and other useful parameters. The field I want to pass to Authot entity from FOSUserBundle is the "Name" field. Then I want to cascade the FOSUser entity and if its deleted, delete also the Author entity.

So schematically FOSUserBundle.username => Author.name

I do not know how to implement this code except that it has a @ORM/OneToOne relationship. Any ideas please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to insert the Author manually after your user registration is completed.  The FOSUserBundle provides a way to hook into events like post registration completion.  You can create a listener to the `FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED` event and create your Author entity there.

See documentation here: https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/controller_events.md

For example:

**services.yml:**

```
services:
    my_user_registration_service:
        class: MyBundle\EventListener\MyUserRegistrationListener
        arguments: [@doctrine.orm.entity_manager]
        tags:
            - { name: kernel.event_subscriber }
```

**MyUserRegistrationListener:**

```
namespace MyBundle\EventListener;

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use FOS\UserBundle\Event\FormEvent;
use FOS\UserBundle\FOSUserEvents;
use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use MyBundle\Entity\Author;

class EventSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $em;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $em)
    {
        $this->em = $em;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            FOSUserEvents::REGISTRATION_COMPLETED => 'addAuthor',
        );
    }

    public function addAuthor(FilterUserResponseEvent $event)
    {
        $user = $event->getUser();

        $author = new Author();
        $author->setName($user->getUsername();

        $this->em->persist($author);
        $this->em->flush();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Jason Roman. Thank you so much for your help. I did not have the latest release of the FOSUserBundle. Your answer has been very useful :D.